# Syntax errow when added where clause to sub select

Tags: sql-server

This query runs fine but, when I add a where clause to any of the subselects except the last one, it generates an error.  Example and error provided below.  Can you help me fix this syntax error?:

```
SELECT Getdate()                                            AS PullTime, 
       (SELECT Min(sqlagentstatus) 
        FROM   dbo.tracksqlagentstatus)                     AS SQLAgentStatus, 
       (SELECT Max(memorygrants) 
        FROM   dbo.trackmemorygrants)                       AS MemoryGrants, 
       (SELECT Avg(pagelifeexpectancy) 
        FROM   trackple)                                    AS PLE, 
       (SELECT Avg(freepages) 
        FROM   dbo.trackfreepages)                          AS FreePages, 
       (SELECT Avg(sqlprocesscpu) 
        FROM   dbo.trackcpu 
        WHERE  capturetime > Dateadd(minute, -5, Getdate()))AS CPU
```

I need to add a where clause to some of the sub-queries but, when I do as shown below, it generates an error.  Do you know what I can do to fix this error?

```
SELECT Getdate()                                             AS PullTime, 
       (SELECT Min(sqlagentstatus) 
        FROM   dbo.tracksqlagentstatus)                      AS SQLAgentStatus, 
       (SELECT Max(memorygrants) 
        FROM   dbo.trackmemorygrants)                        AS MemoryGrants, 
       (SELECT Avg(pagelifeexpectancy) 
        FROM   trackple)                                     AS PLE, 
       (SELECT Avg(freepages) 
        FROM   dbo.trackfreepages )                          AS FreePages
        WHERE  capturetime > Dateadd(minute, -5, Getdate()), 
       (SELECT Avg(sqlprocesscpu) 
        FROM   dbo.trackcpu 
        WHERE  capturetime > Dateadd(minute, -5, Getdate())) AS CPU
```

Error Message that is received:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

This is a Microsoft SQL Server Database.

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE for sub-query is outside of the sub-query. Also you should use aliases in sub query if you need to have WHERE. This should work:

```
SELECT Getdate()                                           AS PullTime, 
   (SELECT Min(sqlagentstatus) 
    FROM   dbo.tracksqlagentstatus)                        AS SQLAgentStatus 
   , 
   (SELECT Max(memorygrants) 
    FROM   dbo.trackmemorygrants)                          AS MemoryGrants, 
   (SELECT Avg(pagelifeexpectancy) 
    FROM   trackple)                                       AS PLE, 
   (SELECT Avg(freepages) 
    FROM   dbo.trackfreepages X 
    WHERE  X.capturetime > Dateadd(minute, -5, Getdate())) AS FreePages, 
   (SELECT Avg(sqlprocesscpu) 
    FROM   dbo.trackcpu 
    WHERE  capturetime > Dateadd(minute, -5, Getdate()))   AS CPU
```